# sed, insert file before last line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, unix, sed

The following inserting file method for `sed` used to be working, even before last line, but not any more. Is it a bug in the current `sed`?

Demo of inserting file method with sed:

```
mkdir /tmp/test
printf '%s\n' {1..3} > /tmp/test/f1
printf '%s\n' {one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten} > /tmp/test/f2

$ cat /tmp/test/f2 | sed -e "/nine/r /tmp/test/f1" -e //N
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
1
2
3
nine
ten

$ head -9 /tmp/test/f2 | sed -e "/nine/r /tmp/test/f1" -e //N
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
1
2
3

$ cat /tmp/test/f2 | sed -e "/ten/r /tmp/test/f1" -e //N
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
1
2
3

$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
...
```

I.e., the inserting file before the line method works everywhere except the last line. It used to be working before. Is it a bug in the current `sed`?

Thanks

Comment: I've been trying hard to achieve it without success. I would switch to `awk` or `perl`, but just curiosity, which was the previous working version?

Comment: I don't quite understand the mechanics of //N. But if you want to prepend text before the last line, why not just append it to the line before last?  So, skip the //N then it will always append.  Now you want text from file f1 before the last line `$ echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour' | sed -e '/three/r ./f1'`

Comment: *"why not just append it to the line before last?"* The problem is that you can't predict what the line before last would be, so I HAVE TO **match against the last line**, then insert before it. @Birei, I didn't keep the version, neither I kept the time I test it. But I dig the above from my note, which had been working before.

Comment: @xpt I agree it'd be better to be more generic but you are predicting the last line because in your example you are stating it explicitly /ten/  so knowing beforehand that 'ten' was the last line.

Comment: Exactly @barlop. Just like an html file, you don't know what its contents are, but a well formed html file would always have '`</body>`' as the last time. Just an e.g.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're on `gnu sed` you could use

```
'e [COMMAND]'
     This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into
     pattern space.
```

on the la`$`t line:

```
sed '$e cat insert.txt' file
```

With `ed` (replace `,p` with `w` if you want to edit-in-place):

```
ed -s file<<IN
- r insert.txt
,p
q
IN
```

or

```
ed -s file <<< $'-1 r insert.txt\n,p\nq\n'
```

When `ed` reads `file` the current address is set to the la`$`t line. `-` (or `-1`) sets the current address to one line before (i.e. `$-1`) and `r` reads in `insert.txt` to after the current line. `,p` prints the content of the text buffer (as I said, replace with `w` to save changes) and `q` quits editor.

Comment: That works perfectly! (Tested with `sed '$e cat /tmp/test/f1' /tmp/test/f2` using the files given in OP). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

According to your comment you "HAVE TO **match against the last line**", so I would consider using the `$` (last line) and `i` (insert command) in `sed`. For example:

```
sed '$ i\INSERT BEFORE LAST LINE' number.txt
1
2
3
4
INSERT BEFORE LAST LINE
5
```

Just make sure that the file doesn't have an empty line as the last line and it should work. Note the the space between the dollar sign and the `i` and the backslash (`\`) after the `i`. This will insert the text after the backslash to the last line without needed a `/pattern/` for the last line.

NOTE: This command will only add one line of text before the final line, not a file. If you want to insert the contents of a file before the last line.

If you want to add an entire file (and you don't if it's in `sed`) I would use this:

```
    head -n-1 first_file.txt && cat inserted_file.txt && tail -n1 first_file.txt
```

This should display everything except the last line, then `cat` the the `inserted_file.txt` and then display the last line of the `first_file.txt`.

Comment: that puts a line before the last line but he said insert a **file**  before the last line

Comment: This method puts a line **before** the last line, but it doesn't insert a file that it true. I'll make note of that in my answer. Thanks

Comment: your 'answer' might be worthy as a comment but i'm sure the op is aware of it and it doesn't answer the question